# Selecting different subtype values in one query

Tags: sql, oracle, subtype

I'm new with oracle and handling subtypes. I need to select an album that is of MP3_TYPE and both values of MEDIA_TYPE in DISK_TYPE: Vinyl, Audio CD.

Here is the create subtype query:

```
create or replace type disk_type under album_type 
( mediaType         varchar(10),
  diskNum           number(2), -- number of disks
  diskUsedPrice     number(9,2),
  diskDeliveryCost  number(9,2), 
  overriding member function discountPrice return number)
/
create or replace type mp3_type under album_type
(downloadSize   number, -- size in MB
overriding member function discountPrice return number)
/
```

I can select all 3 types individually but it doesn't seem to be working when all 3 are in the one query. Not great with treat functions so assuming it is some syntax issue.

Here is what I've done:

```
select
    t1.albumtitle
from albums t1
where value(t1) IS OF (mp3_type) 
    and treat(value(t1) as disk_type).mediatype = 'Vinyl'
    and treat(value(t1) as disk_type).mediatype = 'Audio CD';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That SQL statement doesn't look like Oracle syntax. Are you sure you've tagged the correct database platform?

Comment: oracle sql developer, have been told it is the same

Comment: Hmm. Seems like maybe it is valid syntax, but one I've never come across before! (I've never had to use objects in this way.) You're using this SQL in PL/SQL then?

Comment: yep that's correct, any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the DDL for the albums table.

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to be working" mean - do you get an error, or the wrong data, or no data? (I'm guessing no data...) It would be helpful to include the `album_type` definition plus sample insert statements and the result you expect to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you've shown so far, `mp3_type` and `disk_type` are both subtype of `album_type`. Which seems reasonable. But that means a single object in the table cannot be both subtypes at once; so it can't have the attributes of both subtypes.

If a row is `mp3_type` then treating it as `disk_type` doesn't cause the `disk_type` attributes to be set. When you treat that object as `disk_type` those attributes will be - *must* be - null.

```
insert into albums values (album_type('ABC'));
insert into albums values (mp3_type('BCD', 123));
insert into albums values (disk_type('DEF', 'Vinyl', 1, 12.34, 1.23));

select
    t1.albumtitle
from albums t1
where value(t1) IS OF (mp3_type) 
    and treat(value(t1) as disk_type).mediatype = 'Vinyl'
    and treat(value(t1) as disk_type).mediatype = 'Audio CD';

no rows selected

select
    t1.albumtitle,
    treat(value(t1) as disk_type).mediatype
from albums t1
where value(t1) IS OF (mp3_type);

ALBUMTITLE                     TREAT(VALU
------------------------------ ----------
BCD
```

> I need to select an album that is of MP3_TYPE and both values of MEDIA_TYPE in DISK_TYPE: Vinyl, Audio CD

If it is MP3_TYPE then MEDIA type is null; but even with a `disk_type` entry the media type cannot be *both* Vinyl and CD at the same time.

Perhaps you just meant or use `or` instead of `and`:

```
select
    t1.albumtitle,
    treat(value(t1) as mp3_type).downloadsize as downloadsize,
    treat(value(t1) as disk_type).mediatype as mediatype
from albums t1
where
    value(t1) IS OF (mp3_type) 
    or (
        value(t1) IS OF (disk_type)
        and (
            treat(value(t1) as disk_type).mediatype = 'Vinyl'
            or treat(value(t1) as disk_type).mediatype = 'Audio CD'
        )
    );

ALBUMTITLE                     DOWNLOADSIZE MEDIATYPE 
------------------------------ ------------ ----------
BCD                                     123           
DEF                                         Vinyl
```